# Why Code Map does not work on Unity projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, code-map

When you try to invoke Code Map against a Unity project, you get an errror icon and none of the elements can get expanded:

[image]

Why is that and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default, projects are not fully built. Fortunately, there is an option for that:

[image]